# regex validator, required field

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to use the regular expression validator for a numeric ID field. The field needs to be a required field of any number. Currently, I'm using:

```
="\d{1,}"
```

Shouldn't this make it so the user has to at least enter 1 digit?? If I hit the submit button with the field empty, it passes validation and posts back.. But if I enter non-numeric characters, it errors fine. If I wanted zero or more occurrences, I'd use: `="(\d{1,})?"`

Why isn't this working? Do I need to use this in combination with a Required Field Validator? That would suck ><

Comment: i'm not a regex guru but try \d+

Comment: Sorry, I tried that. It didn't change anything

Comment: what about this one? "^\d{0,9}$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set the property `ValidateEmptyText` to `true` or else the `CustomValidator` will not fire for empty text.

EDIT:  You can attach a javascript function to the `CustomValidator` to accomplish this since I don't think a `RegularExpressionValidator` will fire against an empty control.  I have created a basic example to illustrate the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckMyText(sender, args) {
        var compare = RegExp("\\d{1,}");
        args.IsValid = compare.test(args.Value);
        return;
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error!"
    ControlToValidate="txtTest" ValidateEmptyText="true"
    ClientValidationFunction="CheckMyText"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I have tested it and it seems to work. Leave a comment if you require further assistance.

Comment: It is a RegularExpressionValidator

Comment: Hmm, actually its not working against special characters. "4/5", "3#", "4'5" all pass validation.. why is that?

Comment: Ooh, I got it. Needed to wrap it with "^$": "^\\d{1,}$"

Answer (score 1):

You still need to use a RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: +1 I was afraid of that. Kelsey showed me a work around with a custom validator :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the user is entering the IDs, but if the input field is TextBox control why don't you use something like this:

```
if (tbID.Text.Length != 0)
{
    //Logic goes here
}
```

Comment: I'd rather have it so it can validate without a post back. I know I can use javascript.. but a regularexpressionvalidator should be able to take care of this for me...

Comment: I don't see any other solution, but a RequiredFieldValidator... Let's wait for someone more experienced than me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks submit, you need to make sure that not only empty strings are captured, below is a regex that looks for any whitespace(tab,space etc) + matches if character is not a digit(0-9)

```
 Dim FoundMatch As Boolean
    Try
        FoundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, "\Dm/rld$/\s", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)

'put your code here
    Catch ex As ArgumentException

'syntax error in regular expression
    End Try
```

I believe you'll need to use postback on your page, if you decide to use RequiredFieldValidator you can use above regex expression for that as well

Hth

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is not using a `CustomValidator` then you can have a `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` for the same control. Found this solution here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1230931.aspx . Normally, this results in the error messages being displaced for the second validator but there is a way to fix that. You just have to set the `Display` property to `dynamic` for both the validators. Now the error messages for both the validators are displayed in the same location. Example code:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="ErrorMsg" ControlToValidate="controlID"
ValidationExpression="regexExpression"
Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="ErrorMsg" ControlToValidate="controlID"
Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`
```